# What is the correct way to reinterpret an entity in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, unsafe-pointers

There are cases when you have to deal with a structure of certain type, but the upstream API requires you to present it though a pointer to another type at other places.

For instance, Unix Bind is expecting its second argument to be a pointer to a `sockaddr`, whereas the constructor should be `sockaddr_in`.

For now I'm sticking to a two-layer `with*`:

```
var sa = sockaddr_in(/* ... */)

withUnsafePointer(to: &sa) { _sa in
  _sa.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) { __sa in
    let err = bind(fd, __sa, socklen_t(saSize))
    precondition(err == 0)
  }
}
```

However, I'm discouraged by noisiness of this approach. When I use `unsafeBitCast` between pointer types:

```
bind(fd, unsafeBitCast(__sa, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<sockaddr>.self), socklen_t(saSize))
```

Then the compiler warns me not to do so, and recommends resort to `withMemoryRebound`.

When I use an in-place constructed pointer:

```
UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: &sa).withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) { _sa in
  let err = bind(fd, _sa, socklen_t(saSize))
  precondition(err == 0)
}
```

Then it works as well as the initial version, and rids us of one level of nesting. Although it looks more frail than `with*`. Also it's unclear, if the in-place pointer is the correct approach, why `withUnsafePointer` even exists.

Having that said, what is the canonical way to reinterpret a structure in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first method is the correct one, using `withUnsafePointer()`
and `withMemoryRebound()`, as one can see from the various examples
provided  in [UnsafeRawPointer Migration](https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift3/se-0107-migrate.html), e.g.

> In Swift 3, the user should explicitly rebind memory to a different
>   type:
>
> ```
> let result = withUnsafePointer(to: &addr) {
>   // Temporarily bind the memory at &addr to a single instance of type sockaddr.
>   $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
>     connect(sock, $0, socklen_t(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.stride))
>   }
> }
> ```

The other approach

```
UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: &sa).withMemoryRebound(...) { ... }
```

looks fragile to me. `sa` is passed as an `inout` parameter to
the constructor of `UnsafeMutablePointer()`, but that *may* be
the address of temporary storage, and there is no guarantee that 
it is still valid when the constructor has returned and the closure
is called.